# Redis connection is failed

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, redis

I'd like to work with Redis for manipulating sessions.But I get failure when running the spring boot app.So I guess that this error is coming from maven dependencies especially version conflicts.

Here is my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Notice that I added two dependencies in above pom.xml which there artifactId are ***spring-session-data-redis*** and ***lettuce-core***.These dependencies are respectively responsible for Redis connection and ensuring thread safety for session connections.

When I run the spring boot app, I get the belowed error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.getConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/aoutir/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.0.10.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisConnection.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

file:/C:/Users/aoutir/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-redis/2.0.10.RELEASE/spring-data-redis-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection

Please any help is very appreciated,thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent a whole day to resolve the exactly same issue. And after a whole day R&D, I found the solution.

```
dependencies {
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis')

runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
runtimeOnly('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')


// runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
```

}

Use 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis' and 'spring-session-data-redis'.
Remove lettuse dependency as it is included in spring-boot-starter-data-redis as dependency.

Here is your dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Even though in my pom, I've following:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>

any idea, what's happening?

Comment: Did you remove lettuse dependency as it is included in spring-boot-starter-data-redis as dependency.?

Answer (score 1):

**Simply delete the explicit version for spring-session-data-redis and go with the version from the spring boot parent pom.**

If you want to change the version of `spring-session-data-redis`, you have to ensure that none of the transitive dependencies is managed by the parent pom. If I downgrade to version 1.3 (version 1.7 could not be found) I end up with the following version mismatch as revealed by `mvn -X dependency:tree`:

```
[ESC[1;36mDEBUGESC[m]    org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[ESC[1;36mDEBUGESC[m]       org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.5.0:compile (version managed from 2.4.2)
[ESC[1;36mDEBUGESC[m]       org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile (version managed from 1.7.10.RELEASE)
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Even though in my pom, I've following:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>

any idea, what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The version management is done automatically and the started will initialize the redis cache.